# iPhone 5 sign into iCloud nuisance message

Tags: icloud, iphone

My iPhone 5 keeps displaying "sign into icloud" by entering my password. I do not know my password or the email address I have for this. I want to clear this from my phone as its there constantly and is stopping me using my phone properly as it interupts an stops me writing texts as it pops up. I have never signed into iCloud and don't want to.

How do I get rid of this message?

Comment: [Have you disabled iCloud yet?](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH2613?locale=en_US)

Comment: I have turned off icloud in the settings, this is driving me mad. The message pops up every two seconds even when im typing a message.